# Ember return length of a model created today

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to do this: I have a model called 'trip', and inside trip, an attribute called 'createdToday', which returns the date when a trip is created. What I want is to return a list of trips that were made today.

Here is my trip model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    driver: DS.belongsTo('driver', {
        async: true,
        inverse: 'trip'
    }),


    ..... etc .......


    createdAt: DS.attr('string', {
        defaultValue() {
            return new Date();
        }
    }),
    isBookedToday: function(trip) {
        var today = new Date().toDateString();
        return (today === trip.get('createdAt').toDateString);
    },
    getTripsToday: Ember.computed('trip.@each.createdAt', function() {
        var tripsToday = this.get('trip');
        return tripsToday.filterBy('isBookedToday', true).get('length');
    })

});
```

In my isBookedToday, I'm trying to see if an individual trip's created time is the same as todays time, and in getTripsToday, I am trying to loop through all the trips and filtering by isBookedToday.

And in my .hbs file, I'm saying: {{trips.getTripsToday}}, which won't render anything, so something's wrong.

I guess I am most confused at Ember's @each and exactly how it works.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to understand that your Trip Model instances represents a *single* Trip! Its absolutely not the right place to put a function that gives you a filtered list of trips!

Next `isBookedToday` is a normal function not a Computed Property. So you can't `filterBy` on it.

You *may* want to implement a `isBookedToday` on your trip, but you definitely have to filter your trips on the same place where you fetch them! Probably in a `model()` hook or a Computed Property on a `component` or a `controller`.

So you *could* do but don't need to do in your `models/trip.js`:

```
...
isBookedToday: Ember.computed('createdAt', {
    get() {
        let now = new Date();
        let created = get(this, 'createdAt');
        return now.getFullYear() === created.getFullYear() &&
            now.getMonth() === created.getMonth() &&
            now.getDate() === created.getDate();
    }
})
...
```

And then in your `model` hook:

```
model() {
    return this.store.findAll('trip').then(trips => trips.filterBy('isBookedToday'));
}
```

Or in a Computed Property in a `controller` or a `component`:

```
tripsToday: Ember.computed('trips.@each.isBookedToday', {
    return get(this, 'trips').filterBy('isBookedToday');
})
```

Be careful. This will result in confusing things if you leave the page open overnight! when your date changes the Computed Properties will *not* recompute automatically!